# Generate Golang grpc + custom proto object

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to generate a gRPC client that returns a self defined proto object. This is my current proto command

`protoc -I.:../ --go_out=plugins=grpc:Muser/messages.proto=github.com/.../.../user:. messages.proto`

and this is the error
`Muser/messages.proto=github.com/.../.../user:./: No such file or directory`

However this command:

`protoc -I.:../ 
--go_out=Muser/messages.proto=github.com/.../.../user:. messages.proto`

and this one:

`protoc -I.:../ --go_out=plugins=grpc:. messages.proto`

work perfectly. The problem is when I try to use the `plugins:grpc` part in conjunction to the path of the `user/messages.proto` file.

Any clue what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Per the protoc documentation here: https://github.com/golang/protobuf#parameters

> To pass extra parameters to the plugin, use a comma-separated parameter list separated from the output directory by a colon:

So I believe the right command would be:
`protoc -I.:../ --go_out=plugins=grpc,Muser/messages.proto=github.com/.../.../user:. messages.proto`